# Zend Form can't load JQuery

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, jquery-ui-datepicker

I followed through this tutorial

> http://zendgeek.blogspot.com/2009/07/zend-framework-and-jquery-jquery-date.html

when I done I found Only 2 text boxes are displayed. Datepicker is not loaded. so, not the problem with class library inclusion rather it may be something else that I can't figure out.

Comment: You are not just going to give up? You are asking for another tutorial instead? I don't understand your question but please, look into why your JQuery is not loading, it should work fine after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skimmed that tutorial, it didn't seem very indepth. Don't give up. Just like most things, getting started is the hardest part. I would suggest you follow the tutorials on Zend Casts. Here is one about getting started with ZF and Jquery: http://www.zendcasts.com/working-with-zendx_jquery/2010/07/